# Join data frames with multiple conditions

Tags: join, dplyr

I have two large data frames (gpr1 = 94991 rows and 12 vars, and eff1 = 946 rows and 21 vars). I need to join them where the VesselID matches, and where the POSITION_DATETIME from the gpr df lies inside the TripStartDateTime and the TripEndDateTime from the eff df. I am struggling to work out how to do this as I usually only join by an identifiing key and no other conditions. I have tried to add my script in all the correct ways i.e. indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut, but I can't for the life of me get it to accept my code in the question. I will include it in a comment. In summary, however, I receive the following error with the script I used: Warning: Detected an unexpected many-to-many relationship between `x` and `y`. Ultimately I end up with the error and a dataframe that has 20075981 rows and 32 vars. Any tips on adding script to stack questions would also be great! I was also unable to attach a repro data set without getting the error and stack thinking it was badly formatted script but am happy to forward this on.

Comment: my script: gpr_eff <- inner_join(gpr,eff1, by = "VesselID") gpr_eff <- gpr_eff %>%
  filter(POSITION_DATETIME >= TripStartDateTime, POSITION_DATETIME <= TripEndDateTime)

Comment: Hello, @Angela, welcome to SO. Your problem appears to be simple, but, in order to get help, pleade, provide some sample data. If you have two data-frames (gpr and eff1, right?), try `dput(head(dpr))`, `dput(head(eff1))` and copy-paste the results on your question. Also, here's a must-read: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example

Comment: that is part of the problem...when I include the sample data I get this error in red: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: I'm happy to send it to you if you want to take a look

Comment: If you're using RStudio, @Angela, try the `reprex` pkg/addin: https://reprex.tidyverse.org/ . It will help you to create the reproducible example.

Comment: Also, try to minimize the data selecting only essentials columns (like Vessel ID, POSITION_DATETIME). Maybe a smaller df won't cause formatting problems.